# auto incremental registration number

Tags: php, codeigniter

I followed youtube tutorial but my codes are not working
I want to auto increase registration number
this is what I tried

in model code

```
public function auto() {
    $regNO = "reg";
    $query = 'select max(registerNO) as regNO_auto from student';
    $data = $this->db->query($query)->row_array();
    $max_regNO = $data['regNO_auto'];
    $max_regNO2 = (int)substr($max_regNO,7,3);
    $regNOcount = $max_regNO2+1;
    $regNO_auto = $regNO."-".sprintf('%07s', $regNOcount);
    return $regNO_auto;
}
```

in view code

```
<?php
  $regNO = $this->members_m->auto();
  echo form_input([
   'name'=> 'registerNO',
   'class'=>'form-control',
   'value'=>set_value('registerNO', $regNO),
   'readonly'=>'true']);
 ?>
```

Why does this only show the last regNo without increment, thus giving a a static regNo?

Comment: what is `registerNO` in student table?

Comment: registerNO is the registration number of a new student applicant. this is what i want to get reg-000001 which will be incremental

Comment: In your database, define the `registerNo`'s type as `big serial`,